# How to use async.eachOfSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, async.js

I'm building an app with Express, Postgres for DB and Sequelize for ORM.

I also imported async utility module.

I have a model `Post` and it has a title. When I pass with the query `title=One&title=Two&title=Three` I want to create 3 posts with these titles.

I tried this:

```
async.eachSeries(req.query.title, function(value, callback) {
  console.log(value);
  Post.create({
    title: value
  });
});
```

But it only creates one post, 'One', and it only logs `One`.

How do I set it correctly to create post for each req.query?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the async library but perhaps the callback function should be `async` and the call to `Post.create()` should have either an `await` before it or return the promise it creates?

Answer (score 0):

A Querystring is an object, so you cannot use it as a same object.

"title=One&title=Two&title=Three"  = {title:One}

Another choice is by using an array and convert it by JSON.stringify

```js
var URL  = "http://hostname/?title=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(['One', 'Two', 'Three']));

var arrayTitle = JSON.parse( decodeURIComponent(req.query.title) );
async.eachSeries(arrayTitle , function(value, callback) {
    console.log(value);
    Post.create({
        title: value
    });
});
```